# Download iOS app IPA file from App Store

Tags: ios-appstore, ios

I have an iOS app in the App Store that I have to make some changes to. I lost part of the source code. I would like to download the IPA from the AppStore and then try to decompile it.

1. Can I download the app IPA file from the iOS App Store or my developer account? If yes, how?
2. How can I decompile the IPA if I manage to download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Can I download the app IPA file from the iOS App Store or my developer account? If yes, how?

**No**.

> 2. How can I decompile the IPA if I manage to download it?

**No**, you can't decompile an iOS app IPA to obtain the source code.

Comment: I suspected that it wasn't possible. I already started to rewrite the missing parts. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: This answer is not factually correct. Refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931618/how-to-decompile-ios-apps for a better reference.